# ServiceStack: How to make InMemoryTransientMessageService run in a background

Tags: servicestack

What needs to be done to make InMemoryTransientMessageService run in a background thread? I publish things inside a service using

```
   base.MessageProducer.Publish(new RequestDto());
```

and they are exececuted immediately inside the service-request.

The project is self-hosted.

Here is a quick unit test showing the blocking of the current request instead of deferring it to the background:

- https://gist.github.com/lmcnearney/5407097

Comment: What Messaging Provider are you using? MSMQ.

Comment: The InMemoryTransientMessageService in ServiceStack, it is a simple in-memory queue. So the purpose of the queue is to let the caller wait as little as possible, not to ensure the message is 100% guaranteed to be handled. If I wanted that, I can use Redis: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box. You would have to build your own. Take a look at `ServiceStack.Redis.Messaging.RedisMqHost` - most of what you need is there, and it is probably simpler (one thread does everything) to get you going when compared to `ServiceStack.Redis.Messaging.RedisMqServer` (one thread for queue listening, one for each worker). I suggest you take that class and adapt it to your needs.

A few pointers:

- `ServiceStack.Message.InMemoryMessageQueueClient` does not implement `WaitForNotifyOnAny()` so you will need an alternative way of getting the background thread to wait to incoming messages.
- Closely related, the ServiceStack.Redis implementation uses topic subscriptions, which in this class  is used to transfer the `WorkerStatus.StopCommand`, which means you have to find an alternative way of getting the background thread to stop.
- Finally, you may want to adapt `ServiceStack.Redis.Messaging.RedisMessageProducer` as its `Publish()` method pushes the message requested to the queue and pushes the channel / queue name to the TopicIn queue. After reading the code you can see how the three points tie together.

Hope this helps...